# Transaction and stored procedure. Why log table is empty in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

I am very new in Mysql, probably don't know or don't understand something essential.

Could you please advise me why 'begin !!!' message is not inserted in this
[case](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fBGdMLArHqZWrqqW9vPTZS/0)?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TABLE `_debugLogTable` (
  `Message` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB $$


CREATE PROCEDURE `debug_msg`(msg VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
        insert into _debugLogTable select msg;
END$$


 CREATE FUNCTION `ValueMeetsCondition`(value varchar(20)) RETURNS tinyint(1)
BEGIN
    DECLARE ConditionValue INTEGER;

    call debug_msg('begin !!!');

    SET ConditionValue = CAST(`value` AS UNSIGNED);

    call debug_msg('end !!!');

    RETURN TRUE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I am aware that `CAST` function fails, but why `call debug_msg('begin !!!');` does not insert new record into table?! There are not any transactions there!

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's a good observation. But the call/insert in question is performed/tried *before* that error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Taking into account that there are not any transactions , i expect that first statement will be executed even if second statement fails. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Disappointed I *cannot guarantee* but I might have read it somewhere that Triggers/Stored Procedures/Stored Routines (Functions) are executed within a transaction. That is why we face locking/deadlock related issues with Triggers especially.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Thank you. I will check it. I am really wondered, that such an easy question(i would say even trivial) has not response ... And i don't understand why. Or MySql community here is small or maybe i formulated my question in a wrong way\with wrong title or something else ... I am really wondered

Comment: @Disappointed generally MySQL (and other RDBMS) answerers on SO focus on SQL query formulation related questions. There is less response on Triggers/Stored Routines etc. You may try following two forums: https://forums.mysql.com/ and https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Probably you were right. I posted my own answer if you are interested. Thank you for advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want post an answer, maybe it will help somebody in the future.
From [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html) we have -

> If autocommit mode is enabled, each SQL statement forms a single transaction on its own. By default, MySQL starts the session for each new connection with autocommit enabled, so MySQL does a commit after each SQL statement if that statement did not return an error. If a statement returns an error, the commit or rollback behavior depends on the error

I call function in this way - `select ValueMeetsCondition('>10')`. 

So actually it is wrapped into transaction by MySQL, that's why if something inside my procedure fails - the whole changes are roll backed.
If i remake my query in this way the message `begin !!` will be inserted, while `end !!` does not

```
call debug_msg('begin !!!');

SET ConditionValue = CAST(`>10` AS UNSIGNED);

select ConditionValue;

call debug_msg('end !!!');
```

Comment: Have you tried you original query by disabling auto-commit mode ? Do try that, and let know if the behaviour is on expected lines !

Comment: just tried it and disable autocommit mode. Result is the same as in original question - `begin !!` is not inserted

Comment: I think that it *confirms* that stored routines/triggers are *always* executed within a Transaction. So changing auto-commit mode does not affect.